# PostgreSQL: Automated Backup in Windows

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I'm trying to create an automated backup in Postgresql using below link, but I don't know where to find the needed dll, I'm stuck here. Can't proceed to next instruction because of this. Can anyone knows how to do it? Need help please.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows

```
comerr32.dll
gssapi32.dll
k5sprt32.dll
krb_32.dll
libeay32.dll
libiconv2.dll
libpq.dll
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
msvcm80.dll
msvcp80.dll
msvcr80.dll
pg_dump.dll
ssleay32.dll
zlib1.dll
```

Here's batch file script:

```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
    set dow=%%i
   set month=%%j
   set day=%%k
   set year=%%l
  )
  set datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
  echo datestr is %datestr%

  set BACKUP_FILE=<backup_name_>_%datestr%.backup
  echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
  SET PGPASSWORD=<password>
  echo on
  bin\pg_dump -i -h <localhost> -p 5432 -U <postgres> -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% <db_name>
```

Is there missing syntax?

When manually executed error shows:

```
bin\pg_dump: illegal option -- i
```

Comment: Have you tried it without additional DLLs? That wiki page was written nine years ago; I'm not sure any of this still applies. If you do run into problems, try the version of `pg_dump` included in the [Postgres installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#windows).

Comment: I tried it, but nothing happens.. created a task schedule, executed but no dumping of database backup.. Is it really possible?

Comment: Did you try running the `pg_dump` command manually?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it manually.. Just created task for the batch file  I made.

Comment: Just enter the commands from the batch file into a command prompt.

Comment: Does the batch file work if you run it manually?

Comment: It shows error: `datestr is 01_26_2017 
The system cannot find the specified backup file name is 
The syntax of the command is incorrect`

I just input script in the batch file.

Comment: What's unclear about "*illegal option --i*"?

Comment: I just remove the `-i` then it works manually.. but when using task schedule, nothing happens again.. waaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Failing scheduled jobs are almost always caused by permission problems because the Job runs under a different user. e.g. the current directory of the job is not what you expect it to be and thus pg_dump can't write the backup file. Or `bin\pg_dump` does not exist because the current directory is a different one where the relative directory `bin` does not exist. Try fully qualified path names for **all** file references.  You should also add a `1> c:\pg_dump.log 2>&1` at the end of the line calling pg_dump to get a logfile with all pg_dump messages

Comment: after this command line: `bin\pg_dump  -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% DB_Name`   or  `bin\pg_dump c:\pg_dump.log  2 -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% DB_Name`   I honestly, don't know what to add and where it to add.

Comment: You can try PostgreSQL-Backup https://postgresql-backup.com to perform automated backups of your PostgreSQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

I execute something like this

```
pg_dump.exe -h %SERVER% -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -d %basedatos% -v -f %filebackup%
```

This variables replace value respective.

Comment: error: `pg_dump.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command `

Comment: You must run with the path where you have installed postgre.  Example:  "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe" -h YOURSERVER -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -d YOURDATABASE -v -f YOURTARGETFILE

Comment: error: `pg_dump.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: the pg_dump.exe must be executed from the directory where you installed the PostgreSQL