# How to fix Automated Backup script for postgres [Window]?

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file

I have look up a duplicate question [PostgreSQL: Automated Backup in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865507/postgresql-automated-backup-in-windows) and other source https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows. I have try to make a simple batch script for my own [eg. Setup Path , Set up password... etc] in order to do restore database in the future. However, it seems like my batch script for backup database does not work at all. I can't figure out where is my mistaken point.

Here is my batch script for backup postgres database.

```
@echo off    
   SET PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910&123
   set root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\
   echo on  
   cd %root%
   echo on 
   pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" testdb
```

Updated Script follow @Gerhard Barnard answer

```
@echo off    
  echo 192.168.1.161:5432:_wolfcom:postgres:R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^&>"%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" _wolfcom
  pause
```

Comment: What is the error you get? And why are you using the pgAdmin binaries and not the Postgres binaries?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It does not happen anything when i run batch script. However, if i run command manually thourgh cmd by using ``` pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" testdb``` and fill required password it can create backup file.

Comment: Does it work if you run `pg_dump` manually on the command line (preferably the one from the Postgres directory, not  the one from the pgAdmin directory)

Comment: Yes it does create backup file. However, i want to skip fill password part that required for connecting database that's why i try to set password for  backup file.

Comment: Might be caused by the `&` or `%` in the password. Try `SET "PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910&123"` (note the double quotes)

Comment: Right now . My problem is - I don't know solution to skip a part that required to fill password and make as a script file to do backup file based schedule that i have setup on window.

Comment: Using `PGPASSWORD` should work, but the `SET` statement probably chokes on the `%` and/or the `&` and your script does not even reach the `pg_dump` part. Did you try my suggestion using double quotes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it does not happen anything i have try `SET "PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910&123"` as you said.

Comment: `SET "PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910^&123"` note the double quotes from the variable name to end of value and caret escape on the `&`. When you do it without the caret, it will set the variable, but echoing it it physically uses the `&` operator, so you need to escape it.

Comment: You should **edit** your batch file to do that, then run the batch file to see if it works. Of course a `SET` on its own won't change anything

Comment: I have change follow @GerhardBarnard suggestion.It still does not run command because i see an path error when i add `pause` in script.   `D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp>C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456789.backup" _wolfcom
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. `.

Comment: Here is my new script. `@echo off    
   SET "PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910^&123"
   SET root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\
   echo on 
   %root%pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456789.backup" _wolfcom
   pause`

Comment: Well that is different.. ALWAYS wrap paths in double quotes.. `set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"` and `cd "%root%"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard  It looks like password authentication is failed 
 Here is what console show `D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456789.backup" _wolfcom
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "_wolfcom" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: So as per your updated script, i means my answer solved your issue?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, your answer is correct. I have mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Ok cool. Glad you are sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should wrap all paths in double quotes to eliminate whitespace. Keep in mind `cmd` interprets each space delimited work as a new command. We need to escape the `&` as it will become a physical operator in batch, lastly it is prefered to use the `/d` option when using `cd` in case you come from another drive letter:

```
@echo off    
 SET "PGPASSWORD=%Ech0-5910^&123"
 set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
 cd /d "%root%"
 pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" testdb
```

Also note, you never use the password in your `pg_dump` command, so you need to consider that as well. Best practice is to edit

```
%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

and add

```
*:5432:*:username:password
```

to automate that part in your script:

```
@echo off
  echo *:5432:*:postgres:%Ech0-5910^&123>""%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" testdb
```

If the `dir` does not exist, create it `"%APPDATA%\postgresql"`

Comment: I have access to `%APPDATA%` on my account and try to find `postgresql\pgpass.conf`, but i found only pgAdmin folder. What am i missing ?.

Comment: Here is path of `%APPDATA%`  -> `C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: Yes, i have checked `%APPDATA%` by echo through cmd and it show  `C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: I have run follow your answer `dir /s | find /i "pgpass.conf"` from root of c: . Console does not show anything about location of pgpass.conf

Comment: I don't have postgresql folder what i have is pgAdmin

Comment: Thank you right now,  i can create backup file, but the backup file size is 0 like a blank file instead of 70 mb file [I have check estimate size by manually backup through pgAdmin UI ].

Comment: `%` is missing while it save to pgpass.conf. Is there anyway to avoid ignore ``%``.

Comment: the password that i set is `R0m3o%Ech0-5910^&`  - > Actual password that save is  `R0m3oEch0-5910&`

Comment: If you set `PGPASSWORD` then passwords in `pgpass.conf` will be ignored. If you want to force pg_dump to use `pgpass.conf`, the batch file shouldn't set `PGPASSWORD` but use some other variable name.

Comment: I have updated my script follow @GerhardBarnard. but why it still ask for password even config has password inside.

Comment: Here is my script `@echo off    
  echo 192.168.1.161:5432:_wolfcom:postgres:R0m3o^%%Ech0-5910^&>"%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgpass.conf"
  set "root=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\"
  cd /d "%root%"
  pg_dump.exe -h 192.168.1.161 -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "D:\Backup\DatabaseBackUp\SQL\123456.backup" _wolfcom
  pause`

Comment: I don't think the file location is correct, perhaps just stick to the original PGPASSWORD SET.. will update answer.

Comment: See update, create the dir `postgresql` in `%APPDATA%` and run the script above again.